# How to set up a JS Require tool to require('net') on the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

So my application is running [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org), which is an extension of node.js.  I'm very new to the JS backend framework scene, and I'm attempting to send a TCP message using a socket from the client side.  However, in order to do that I need to `require('net')`.  How can I do this?  I don't even see the `net` module in my `node_modules` folder - does it not come with `Sails.js`?

How can I resolve this issue?

Also, just for extra clarification, I need to use `require()` on the browser side - apologies for not being more clear in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the node.js net module on the client side. Browsers don't allow you to access plain TCP sockets. That would enable you to circumvent many of their security features, so it simply is not going to happen.

You can implement realtime communication with your own server with web sockets or a wrapper suck as [socket.io](http://socket.io/), but that obviously doesn't let you talk in arbitrary protocols.